# Best way for Battery updates even in background

Tags: android, performance

Hi i am working on an application where i have a service running on my background whole throughout app except when its offline for server tolls but also i m giving user facility to select minimum battery level to continue service running in background ..suppose he selected 50% than have to stop the service when battery goes down to 50%..For which i need tolling battery..Since Action_Battery_Change if registered stops working when my activity or service is destroyed i still need the battery toll to resume my service when battery is up the desired level..Battery_Ok and Battery_Low actions are OS defined...I want a low battery depending on User....And rite now i m using repeationg Alarm service to get the updates which is again  battery consuming and makes no sense since i m trying to save battery by stopping my already running service when battery is low..Any better ideas...where i can get updates in background as well as save most power with memory...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah docs donot recommend you to use Battery Toll and so is  BATTERY_LOW ,BATTERY_OKAY actions are being provided...but in ur case AlarmService inExactRepeating method seems to be best way..but task killers can kill ur Alarm services and thus resulting in your service to never start Again..

Comment: I m starting my service again if user swaitches app on